# Security: WebSocket request whitelist

Tags: c#, security, websocket, cryptography

My problem is that I have a WebSocket server and client model.
With the correct use of my application there won't be any problem. Buut as always you have to think about the bad guys too.

How can I verify that a request is made from my client application and not from some other program (eg. Browser, Malicious program).

Maybe it could work if the client generates a UID to register itself with the server, but how would the server know which UID is whitelisted in the first place?

Edit: I can't put a secret variable in the client request either because it can be decompiled / rev. engineered and extracted.

Happy for any answers :)

Comment: "Maybe it could work if the client generates a UID to register itself with the server, but how would the server know which UID is whitelisted in the first place?" - a better question to ponder might be "if the UID is whitelisted, how can the server know if the client is real, or just using a real client's UID?"

Comment: That's also a good question, I guess it's the same problem with "normal" webapps with tokens. I guess a proxy / malicious program can be defeated with SSL?

Comment: @DatNoHand why not encrypt the content using public key and have a private key in server to decrypt the data?

Comment: @karthick that would work, but doesn't solve the problem of identifying my clients. because the public key is, well public and you can extract it from the build. It could work if every build has it's own unique key, but that is only one more step for the bad guys. Good idea for security tho, +1 :)